# Use an open Excel Workbook To Sum Rows and Columns of Multiple Closed Workbooks That Are in the same folder

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

Is it possible to sum rows and columns of multiple closed excel workbooks that are saved to the same folder and have an identical structure?

I have many workbooks with one sheet and an identical worksheet structure.  I'd like to sum the rows and columns of all the closed workbooks so that my open workbook has consolidated all of the closed workbooks.   Similar to the image below.  It's my understanding and validated through testing that sumif and sumifs can not handle sum data from a closed workbook.

[image]

Comment: This requires a VBA solution where you loop through the closed workbooks to retrieve the data from them.

Comment: Or you reference those workbooks in an excel formula but the values will only update when the workbook is being opened locally.

Comment: If you have establish a connection even the workbooks are closed you can work with that information and then to the calculation you want to do. You can link Workbooks in excel.

Answer (score 0):

I did some additional research and learned that workbook consolidation can be accomplished with PowerQuery. Excel MVP, Gasper Kamensek, has produced a great YouTube video that walks you through the process step-by-step.  I have completed the process two different times and it works perfectly.   Here's a link to the video:

[Consolidate Data from All Excel Worksheets in Multiple Excel Workbooks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iz40zAvyOBI)